# After installing with pip, "jupyter: command not found"

Tags: ubuntu, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

After installing with `pip install jupyter`, terminal still cannot find `jupyter notebook`.

Ubuntu simply says `command not found`.  Similar with `ipython`.  Did `pip` not get install properly or something?  How does Ubuntu know where to look for executables installed with `pip`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter notebook command does not work on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029029/jupyter-notebook-command-does-not-work-on-mac)

Comment: This is not only Mac related. In both systems, my proposal solves the case.

Comment: seems like this should be here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu

Comment: great question. so many answers and none of them work for me when using `brew` on `high sierra`

Comment: Also just a minor note: I needed the "--user" flag when installing, so `python3 -m pip install --user jupyter` worked for me

Comment: Related Windows question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034866/running-jupyter-via-command-line-on-windows

Answer (score 253, accepted):

you did not log out and log in ? It should be on your path to execute. 
If not, pip installed executables in .local, so in a terminal:

```
 ~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

should start notebook

Comment: pip does not put jupyter on your path.  This is a blunder in the docs for jupyter installation.

Comment: Hi, this works for me, but I would like to understand why. I used sudo to pip install jupyter, shouldnt it be a system-wide install ?

Comment: @DeanSchulze, hey then how does one install it?

Comment: I wonder this is not a solution. One should be able type "jupyter" command. [emunsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4619397/emunsing) has a better, complete [aswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38257349/7388116).

Comment: Is there any tip for running it on WSL Debian? I tried all the advices on this post, no avail.

Comment: Still says command not found.  Something just destroyed my working jupyter installation. I think pip destroyed it.  This is ubuntu os, the most popular linux IIRC. It is for a coursera course which gave me the commands it needed to install course requirements for software libs.

Answer (score 284):

Try

`python -m notebook`

Or, if you used pip3 to install the notebook:

`python3 -m notebook`

On Mac OS Catalina and brewed Python3.7

Comment: I have Mas OS Catalina, and yes this solution have worked for me ! But I don't know why the command `jupyter notebook` doesn't work anymore ?

Comment: The only one worked for me for python3.6 on Ubuntu (but of course I ran `python3.6 -m notebook` instead), That's because I installed Jupyter using pip3.6 (which I wanted).

Comment: This works but it just shows the plain notebook view, not the jupyter lab view

Comment: I tried executing the 'python3 -m notebook' syntax and it worked for me. I have installed the jupyter notebook without installing anaconda on my M2 chip Macbook Air. I'm now able to use the notebook with Visual Studio Code without doing any update to the $PATH variable etc.

Answer (score 168):

To be able to run `jupyter notebook` from terminal, you need to make sure that `~/.local/bin` is in your path.

Do this by running `export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin` for your current session, or adding that line to the end of `~/.bashrc` to make your changes last for future sessions (e.g. by using `nano ~/.bashrc`). If you edit ~/.bashrc you will need to log out and log back in to make see your changes take effect.

Comment: For changes to made to `~/.bashrc`, there is no need to log out and then back in. Just do `source ~/.bashrc` and that will suffice.

Comment: For those using zsh, you can update `~/.zshrc` and then `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 88):

I tried both,

```
pip install jupyter
```

and

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

but finally got it done using

```
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```

execute a command as another user -H

The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default) as specified by the password database. Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.

Comment: This worked for me on macOS High Sierra running in a virtual env

Comment: I ran into issues later by using SUDO with pip. Generally you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @TomAranda ... but that assumes that you know what's going on in your environment. That's often not the case. This is simply list of commands that might work for some people with no guarantees what it breaks. I am sure that if OP understand all the implications and what was the problem in first place, they would explain.
I still find those snippets helpful even though it's not the exact answer to the problem.
It's complicated world of package dependencies, sometimes it's just not worth to understand exactly what's going on. Unless it's a lunar orbit software.

Answer (score 42):

Execute this in Terminal

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Worked for me on Ubuntu 16.10, Python3, Anaconda3

**UPDATE**

Add path in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc(if you are using zsh bash) file

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

add the below line to the file

```
PATH=~/path/to/anaconda:$PATH
```

Close the file with

```
esc + : + wq
```

Comment: this worked for me! I did install anaconda beforehand

Comment: Please read again the question. I have described the anaconda install scenario, but the question is related to the pip.
>After installing with pip install jupyter

Answer (score 15):

If jupyter run by this command:

```
~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

simply run this command in terminal

```
 export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 15):

On Mac Os High Sierra, I installed jupyter with

```
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

And then, binary were installed in:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

Answer (score 15):

After installation of Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu I got below error:

Exception: Jupyter command  'jupyter-notebook' not found.

I used simple command it's working for me

> pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir jupyter

Source: http://commandstech.com/how-to-install-jupyter-on-ubuntu16-04-with-pictures-commands-errors-solution/

After exit from root user then execute :

> jupyter notebook

Comment: That worked in my mac too. I spent 3 hours trying to figure this out and none of the solutions worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This works for me too! My problem was that `pip3 install jupyter` did not even install `~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook`. After running your solution, that fixed this problem!

Answer (score 14):

On Mac OS you need to export `~/.local/bin` inside your `$PATH` variable.

```
# Edit the bash profile:
$ vim ~/.bash_profile

# Add this line inside ~/.bash_profile:
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin

# Update the source:
$ source ~/.bash_profile

# Open Jupyter:
$ jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 8):

- Open a terminal window using Ctrl+Alt+T.
- Run the command gedit ~/.profile.
- Add the line. export PATH=$PATH:/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook. to the bottom and save.
- Log out and log in again.

Hopefully this will work.

Answer (score 7):

Here what I did on Linux mint 19:

I installed jupyter with:

```
pip install jupyter
```

and command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

didn't work, so with:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook
```

I fixed the issue, `jupyter notebook` worked then.

Answer (score 6):

Try "pip3 install jupyter", instead of pip. It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Now in the year of 2020.
fix this issue by my side with mac:
`pip install jupyterlab` instead `pip install jupyter`.
there will be an warning before successfully installed keywords:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4bEr.png)

you can see the path with jupyterlab
then you just need to start jupyter notebook by following in path:

```
jupyter-lab
```

notebook will automatic loaded by your default browser.

Answer (score 5):

`python3 -m jupyterlab` worked for me!

For me, it's after `pip install jupyterlab`, can't use jupyter-lab in command line directly. but `python3 -m jupyterlab` worked.

Answer (score 4):

I tried everything and at the end this worked for me on Raspberry pi 4 running Raspbian os

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core
```

Answer (score 3):

**The only thing that worked** me is to export to PATH the Python version that is related to the pip3 of course :) (after a lot of struggling) 
just run:

```
which pip3
```

you should get something like (in Mac):

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3
```

Now run:

```
export PATH=/Library/Python/3.6/bin:$PATH
```

If it works for you :) just add it to your 
`bashrc` or `zshrc`

Answer (score 2):

I see this error in 2023 and `pip install jupyter` and set env path doesn't really help. I solved this by running `pip install notebook` as well.

Because I see in `jupyter --version` command that shows `notebook is not installed`.

I made a guess of the required package name and it just worked for me:)

Answer (score 2):

`jupyter` and `jupyter-notebook` are two different things. you install notebook with

```
pip install notebook
```

and start a notebook with

```
jupyter-notebook
```

you install `jupyter` with

```
sudo snap install jupyter
```

Most likely users who installed `noteebok` want to start with `jupyter` command. But its command is `jupyter-notebook`

[What is the difference between jupyter and jupyter-notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155881/what-is-the-difference-between-jupyter-and-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Jupyter notebook for Python 2 using 'pip' instead of 'pip3' it might work to run:

```
ipython notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-install jupyter with conda:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the command does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Newer Jupyter versions do not come with `notebook` component by default.

Depending on your package manager, you can install `notebook` component by:

```bash
pip install notebook
```

or

```bash
poetry add notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Most generally (in case of jupyter not being in /local/bin) use,

```
which jupyter
```

Example output

```
~/miniconda3/bin/jupyter
```

to see the path for jupyter, then explicitly use that path with sudo

```
sudo ~/miniconda3/bin/jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled python3.7 from the source code, with the following command

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.7.4 --with-ssl
make
make install
```

after `pip3.7 install jupyter` I found the executable is under `/opt/python3.7.4/bin`

check my answer here [Missing sqlite3 after Python3 compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750886/missing-sqlite3-after-python3-compile/57480189#57480189) to get more detail comping python3.7 and pip under ubuntu14.04

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for running jupyter as sudo, when jupyter installed with virtualenv (without sudo) - this worked for me:

First verify this is a PATH issue:

Check if the path returned by `which jupyter` is covered by the sudo user:

```
sudo env | grep ^PATH
```

(As opposed to the current user: `env | grep ^PATH`)

If its not covered - add a soft link from it to one of the covered paths. For ex:

```
sudo ln -s /home/user/venv/bin/jupyter /usr/local/bin
```

Now you sould be able to run:

```
sudo jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Install jupyterlab.

If you get this error:

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

requests 2.25.1 requires idna<3,>=2.5, but you'll have idna 3.1 which is incompatible.
```

Use this:

```sh
pip3 install jupyterlab --use-feature=2020-resolver
```

Comment: It led to ````no such option: --use-feature````

Comment: Hmm, probably they've changes something with new version releases.
Try running it without `--use-feature=2020-resolver` and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOs, this worked for me:

```
/Users/`userName`/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it didn't work until I activated **Virtual Environment**.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled it with

```
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

Then found it with

```
which jupyter
```

under

```
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/miniforge3-4.10.3-10/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: python3 -m notebook worked for

Answer (score 0):

[pypi.org](https://pypi.org/) has two different packages for jupyter and notebook.
On Mac, if you installed the jupyter metapackage (`pip install jupyter`, contraty to `pip install notebook`) then the command `jupyter-notebook` seems to work while `jupyter notebook` does not.

Answer (score 0):

If the installation was successful, just restart your virtual machine (Mine was Oracle).
Then open your terminal, type - Jupyter Notebook -  and hit enter. I will ask your password for the first time launhing. Enter your password and hit unlock. Now you can launch it only typing Jupyter notebook on your terminal. Once it is unlocked, you don't have to enter your password every single time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use anaconda, just do:

> conda install jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

None of the above works for me. It seems that some legacy *jupyter_** packages are incompatible. So:

1. `pip uninstall notebook`
2. `pip uninstall -y $(pip freeze | grep -E '^jupyter.*' | cut -d '=' -f 1)`
3. `pip install notebook`