# jupyter: command not found

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook

I installed jupyter notebook with PIP. 
Now when I want to start it with "jupyter notebook" it says:

> -bash: jupyter: command not found

Anybody has an idea what I could do?

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After installing with pip, "jupyter: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22jupyter%3A+command+not+found%22

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

pip install --user jupyter

This would install in your /home/you/.local/bin.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered here  --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/35318514/9521629

you did not log out and log in ? It should be on your path to execute. If not, pip installed executables in .local, so in a terminal:

```
~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

should start notebook

Comment: i checked this link already thanks.
Does not start with this command?
-bash: /Users/lucakern/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook: No such file or directory