# What is the difference between jupyter and jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, server, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I noticed two commands **jupyter** and **jupyter-notebook** are installed in my desktop within **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** by conda, both are under **python 3.6.7**, 
and I checked their versions by:

```py
$ jupyter --version
# 4.4.0
$ jupyter-notebook --version
# 5.7.4
```

With the help info of the commands, I got:

```
$ jupyter-notebook --help
  The Jupyter HTML Notebook.
  This launches a Tornado based HTML Notebook Server that serves up an
  HTML5/Javascript Notebook client.

$ jupyter --help
  usage: jupyter [-h] [--version] [--config-dir] [--data-dir] [--runtime-dir]
        [--paths] [--json]
        [subcommand]
   Jupyter: Interactive Computing
```

Googled for a while, could not find out any discussion on the difference between the two, although the **help info**s have told me one is *server*, and the other is for *interactive computing*, which is not enough to me. Went to [Jupyter website](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but could not find any description about the version and difference between the two.
Appreciate if anybody could elaborate for me: 
1) what do they differ from each other; 
2) and clarify why the version numbers are different; 
while they seem doing the same job as both pop up the **Notebook** interface from the browser.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `jupyter-notebook` and `jupyter notebook` do same thing - launch a notebook server.  `jupyter` lets you do other things like `jupyter qtconsole` and other subcommands listed in its help.

Answer (score 7):

```
jupyter <subcommand> [options]
```

[`jupyter`](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-command.html) command is used to perform different jupyter-related tasks including starting a jupyter application. The jupyter command is primarily a namespace for subcommands. Check its source code [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/blob/master/jupyter_core/command.py), where the docstring states:

> The root `jupyter` command.
>
> This does nothing other than dispatch to subcommands or output path
>   info.

---

`jupyter-notebook` or `jupyter notebook` is used to start jupyter notebook server and perform tasks related to notebook only.

---

Here, the version numbers are different because

```
$ jupyter --version  # gives you the version of `jupyter` command
# 4.4.0
$ jupyter-notebook --version  # gives you the version of `jupyter notebook`
# 5.7.4
```

Comment: This cleared most of my question, and I need read more. Thanks a lot!