# How do I access python files through jupyter notebooks from the command line if I already have anaconda installed?

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, git-bash

I am using a mac Os X Yosemite

I have anaconda installed on my computer and have always accessed my python files by opening them by clicking on anaconda's icon. However, I would like to access jupyter notebook directly from the command line. I have seen some instructions online but I do not understand terms like 'export bin' etc. What can I do to resolve this issue given that I already have anaconda installed but still want to be able to access it from the cmd?

I typed this in my cmd `jupter notebook` and it gives out the following message.

**-bash: jupyter: command not found**

Comment: Can you open new jupyter notebook from anaconda? What does ```jupyter --version``` and ```jupyter --paths``` returns?

Comment: Yes, I can open jupyter notebook. It says version 6.00.  However, I had to open it separately without using the cmd. When I tried inputing these commands in the cmd, it said 'command not found'.

Comment: Ok, have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found 
Also, try to use ```pip install --upgrade notebook``` in the command line

Comment: @Shan _However, I had to open it separately without using the cmd. When I tried inputting these commands in the cmd..._ Isn’t that contradictory? Is CMD involved here or not?