# Jupyter not launching

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I just installed jupyter using pip3 install jupyter and when I try to launch in termimal  I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/joseph/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "/Users/joseph/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/jupyter_core/command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found

Comment: Look for the hint .. you installed it via pip3 ..but the path it is looking for is ".../Python/2.7/..." and that's why not found

Comment: how do i fix this? @Amit

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the link like "~/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook" or "Users/joseph/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook"? I guess you are using mac ..

Comment: yeah it says no such file or directory exists @Amit