# A beginner needs some help about Python, Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

first of all, I cannot run the Jupyter notebook on my commander. I have both programs but for some reason, my computer doesn't run it. it says

I try to run it like this (I type jupyter notebook on cmd):

'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

and I get that below this sentence. I just started and I have some much to learn but I'd like to do it right and understand. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After installing with pip, "jupyter: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a tad late but anyways...
Assuming you are not using Anaconda, did you install for a user profile or for the whole system?
Run the following in cmd with administrator privileges (elevated command prompt)

```
pip install Jupyter
pip install Jupyter notebook  
pip install Jupyter lab
```

(Last one is useful if you'll use labs in future)

Then run:

```
Jupyter lab
```

Or

```
Jupyter notebook
```

In cmd.
Mind the case of letters! Don't forget the capitals.
This should work.