# jupyter notebook not working in Mac

Tags: python, macos, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I can have already gone through the following questions:

[Jupyter notebook command does not work on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029029/jupyter-notebook-command-does-not-work-on-mac)

[After installing with pip, "jupyter: command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313876/after-installing-with-pip-jupyter-command-not-found)

None of them helped me. I have installed `jupyter` and `notebook` through pip.

The error I get is:

```
➜  ~ jupyter notebook
zsh: permission denied: jupyter
```

So, when I sudo it:

```
➜  ~ sudo jupyter notebook
Password:
sudo: jupyter: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check a couple of issues:

• Verify you have Python correctly installed. I recommend installing with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) for the right dependencies to be installed too:

```
brew install python
```

• You can also install Python and Jupyter Notebook together with the Anaconda package, which installs both them, plus other useful packages for scientific computing and data science:

[Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: Yeah, I have Python installed properly: `/usr/local/bin/python`. I installed jupyter through pip instead of conda as I wanted to use libs like `rpy2` which aren't available in the conda catalogue.

Comment: Wait. Reinstalling Python from `brew` did the trick.  Weird. But, it worked anyway. Thanks :D

Comment: Homebrew is excellent at solving dependencies for every Mac OS X version, which is tricky somehow. :-)